# Springboot_multimodule_project_error

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, multi-module

I have a spring boot project in intellij , my main method runs fine . But when I add a module to it the child module main method was able to run , but the Parent module main method cannot run . Why is that ? : When i try to run it says :
Error: Could not find or load main class com.org.hello.parentpom.ParentPomApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.org.hello.parentpom.ParentPomApplication

I wanted to run the main method of the parent application And was not able to run it .

Comment: What is the structure of your project before and after the change? Can you please elaborate this a bit more?